# Кавычки в названиях спортивных призов

Tags: кавычки, названия

Как оформлять кавычками названия спортивных призов? Например, "Приз им. Рокоссовского" или приз им. Рокоссовского? Как быть, если в призе есть кличка лошади - "Приз Гондолы" или приз "Гондолы"? Или приз Гондолы?

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет без кавычек:

**Приз им. Рокоссовского**

**Приз Гондолы**

Если речь идёт о награде, то обратимся к параграфу ["Названия орденов и медалей"](http://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=172#pp172) раздела "Употребление кавычек" справочника Розенталя:

> Если название награды синтаксически зависит от предшествующего
> слова *орден, знак* и т. п., то оно кавычками не выделяется: *орден
> Мужества, орден Жукова, орден Отечественной войны I степени, орден
> Возрождения Польши, орден Почётного легиона (Франция), медаль Ушакова,
> знак отличия Георгиевский крест и т. п.*

Возможно, имеется в виду не совсем название награды, а название события или организации. Тогда нам поможет параграф ["Названия литературных произведений, органов печати, предприятий и т. д."](http://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=171#pp171):

> 2 . Не выделяются кавычками:
>
> 1 ) собственные наименования, если они не имеют условного характера:
> *Московский государственный университет им. М. В. Ломоносова;
> Владимирский педагогический институт; Московский театр кукол;
> Измайловский парк культуры и отдыха; Институт языкознания Российской
> академии наук*;
>
> 4 ) названия, в состав которых входят слова имени, памяти и т. п.:
> *Театр имени И. В. Гоголя; Больница имени С. П. Боткина; канал имени
> Москвы;*

В [другом параграфе](http://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=174#pp174):

> Примечание. Не выделяются кавычками, но пишутся с прописной буквы
> клички животных: *лошадь Изумруд, корова Белянка, собака Трезор, кот
> Васька, медвежонок Топтыжка, слониха Манька*.

Поэтому нет никаких причин ставить кавычки в указанных примерах.

Учтите, что при использовании [родового наименования](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2) кавычки будут нужны. Например:

**Фонд "Приз Гондолы"**

**ООО "Приз Гондолы"**

Comment: Кирилл, в этой теме вопрос строго конкретный (конный спорт), причем названия нужно уточнить по источнику и привести оттуда примеры, например: http://www.eliseev.ru/ippo/bg_st_priz.html#kiks  Общую теорию лучше не излагать подробно, а показать ее применение на практике (примеры тоже должны касаться этой темы). Спорный вопрос - как писать слово "приз", в СМИ по-разному пишут, вот автор и просить уточнить. Вроде бы прописная буква, но надо это обосновать, а кличку лошади они ставят в кавычки. Я думаю,  ответ нужно подредактировать.

Comment: @Sharon, именно поэтому я почти не отвечаю на вопросы, сложно учесть все языковые нюансы. С удовольствием почитаю ваш ответ.

Comment: Вопрос довольно сложный, специализированный и отчасти философский,  поэтому быстро ответить не получается. Попробую позже.

Answer (score 0):

**1.  Правильное написание**

При решении такой задачи надо ориентироваться как на общие правила, так и специализированные источники, где используется  это название.
На официальном сайте Московского ипподрома указано:  **Приз «Гондолы».**
Для кобыл 4-х лет орловской породы, дистанция 1600 м, приз разыгрывается с 1985 года.
Там же: Приз памяти маршала Г.К. Жукова. Соответственно. правильно: **Приз им. Рокоссовского.**

**2. Почему ставятся кавычки**

По общим правилам при наличии падежного управления  кавычки не нужны и следует писать: **Приз Гондолы.** Однако здесь учитываются особенности темы, поэтому клички лошадей заключаются в кавычки для лучшего понимания названия. Клички бывают самые различные, но **по двум признакам** (форма Р.п. и кавычки) мы сразу узнаем их в составе имени собственного.

Другие названия для сравнения:  Приз «Талантливого» (кавычки, падежное управление, кличка лошади), Приз «Русская зима» (кавычки,  нет падежного управления), Приз Селекционеров (нет кавычек, падежное управление).

**3. Выбор прописной или строчной буквы**

Приз – это вид соревнования, то есть нарицательное существительное и родовое наименование.  Слово «приз» **в начале названия** пишется с прописной буквы (первое слово составного имени собственного), а в середине названия – со строчной, например: ***Приз** имени Российской Федерации, Летний орловский **приз**.*
Но это в официальном названии мы используем прописную букву, в других же случаях родовое наименование «приз» можно сделать **приложением** перед именем собственным: **приз Гондолы**.

**4. И немного «философии»**

Итак, правильные  названия – это Приз «Гондолы»,  Приз «Барса»,  казалось бы, только их следует использовать во всех случаях. Но в реальных текстах можно встретить **разнообразные варианты,** например:

«Для наездников **Приз Барса** как один из главных стартов сезона является также очень престижным и желанным. Главный приз, называемый **«Всероссийским призом Барса»**, в России разыгрывается на Центральном Московском ипподроме в середине июля.  **«Барс»** — один из самых престижных призов для орловского рысака вообще, а для четырёхлетних — главный приз» . [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Приз_Барса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0)

**Почему же мы используем разные названия**, следует ли считать их ошибочными? Дело в том,  что в русском  языке один и тот же обозначаемый предмет (денотат, от лат. denotatum,  обозначенное)  в одном тексте **называется по-разному** (так, для действующего лица в художественном повествовании автор придумывает различные названия).  Это делается для того, чтобы **избежать нежелательных повторов**, которые считаются стилистической погрешностью.  Вот и в данном случае используются варианты, так что можно встретить такие написания: *Приз Гондолы (по общим правилам),  приз «Гондолы», приз  Гондолы.*